# Cropping a CIImage result in an image that is 1px too wide

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-image

I am trying to crop a CIImage:

```
extension CIImage {
  func resize(size: CGSize) -> CIImage {
    // TODO: add padding instead of cropping in the image, to keep the entire input
    let scale = min(size.width, size.height) / min(extent.size.width, extent.size.height)
    let resizedImage = transformed(by: .init(scaleX: scale, y: scale))

    let width = resizedImage.extent.width
    let height = resizedImage.extent.height
    let xOffset = (CGFloat(width) - size.width) / 2.0
    let yOffset = (CGFloat(height) - size.height) / 2.0
    let rect = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    return resizedImage
      .clamped(to: rect)
      .cropped(to: CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: size.width, height: size.height))
  }
}
```

This almost works, but the result is 1px off.

The input dimensions are 1280x720 and I'm trying to get an output that is 513x513 but I get 514x513. This is to be fed to a ML model so I cannot afford to be off by 1px. I am also using MacOS so I don't have access to UIKit.

When I inspect the result, preview shows me that it is 513x513, but `image.extent.size` is 514x513 and the ML model fails...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem there is that `CGFloat` it is not an integer. You need to get rid of the fraction digits generated in your calculations. In this case the issue it is in your origin offset position `199.5`. Btw `width` it is already a `CGFloat`. Try like this:

```
let xOffset = ((width - size.width) / 2).rounded(.down)
let yOffset = ((height - size.height) / 2).rounded(.down)
```